# $L^p$ spaces of tangent sections: reference request

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, lp-spaces

What sorts of books would address $L^p$ spaces of sections of the tangent space of a Riemannian manifold ($C^\infty$, compact, ideally with boundary)?

In particular, I'd like to show that smooth sections are dense in the set of $L^2$-measurable or $L^\infty$ sections, in the $L^2$ norm or $L^\infty$ norm.

I could do this using local orthonormal frames and a partition of unity argument, but I'd prefer a reference which does this directly.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment because I'm not entirely sure if exactly what you want is there, but reading your question, the book *Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds. Monge-Ampere Equations* by Thierry Aubin comes to mind (namely, chapter 2). I still need to study some of the material there properly myself, and here I am recommending the book to people... (don't be like me!)

Comment: I don't think that the claimed density is true for $L^\infty$.

Comment: Good point @PhoemueX, I actually knew that but I'd forgotten (I'm assuming you mean the fact there's no $f \in C^\infty([-1,1])$ for which $\|f-\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}\|_\infty<\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: Also, thanks @Ivo, I'll have a look.